# Why reactive components have less influence at low frequencies?

Tags: ac, input-impedance, circuit-theory

Some textbooks state that reactive components (may) have less influence at low frequencies, since inductance and capacitance are generally more significant at hifh freqs. "Pratical electronics for inventors" is one of them.

I don't understand this statement, since capacitive reactance is inversly proportinal to frequency.

How should such a statement be interpreted? I suppose it assumes something from practical experience, but I'm not able to figure it out.

EDIT: The context of the statement was input and output impedence. From your answers I understand is that from the point of view of a low freq signal entering, or exiting, a circuit the relationship between parasitic impedence and capacitance is more relevant then the overall capacitance (which should increase with low freq).

Comment: At low frequencies an inductor acts like a "short" and at high frequencies acts like an "open." At high frequencies a capacitor acts like a "short" and at low frequencies acts like an "open." Depending upon how either part is used, it will either have "less influence" or "more influence." But it depends upon how the part is used. And an inductance is **not** directly proportional to frequency. It's impedance **is** directly proportional, though.

Comment: I would just ignore that statement. It's just that parasitic capacitances tend to be in parallel and parasitic inductances tend to be in series, and in these positions they are most disruptive (stop signals from going where they need to go) at high frequencies. Of course, if you put in an AC block capacitor which is in series, the behaviour is a good thing...until the frequency is so high the cap's parasitic inductance which is in series starts to interfere. So just ignore that statement. It's not important.

Comment: Here is a pretty good tutorial on Reactive Impedance  (i.e. why Inductors and capacitors don't behave like resistors)  https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/accircuits/ac-resistance.html   It's about as simple as this topic can be.  If this is too much for you,  you'll have to settle to accept the rule-of-thumb as it was given to you because you won't have the background to understand it deeper.

Comment: Kyle B I know the basic theory (and I made a correction to my question where I was saying about induction). The point is that basic theory just tells me that inductance might increase or decrease with freq depending if the circuit exhibits inductive or capacitive behaviour. So a statement sating that reactive elements do not have much relevance at low freq (below 1kHz) cannot be explained with the vasic theory only.

Answer (score 2):

For both capacitors and inductors, their impedance varies with increasing frequency. Inductor impedance *increases* with frequency, while capacitor impedance *decreases* with frequency.

That is:

- Inductive Reactance: \$ X(l) = 2\pi F L\$
- Capactive Reactance: \$ X(c) = \frac {1} {2\pi F C}\$

In system design, parasitic (unwanted) inductance shows up in point-to-point *series* connections, blocking high-frequency current in them. Parasitic capacitance shows up as *shunt* coupling *between* signal connections, with that coupling increasing with frequency.

Stated another way, wires behave less and less like pure connections with increasing frequency because of these \$L\$ and \$C\$ parasitics.

This has influence on high-performance board design. These days, CPU boards tend to use fat power traces or even entire planes devoted to ground and power to minimize inductance. Likewise, capacitance is managed by separating signals from each other, and with controlled impedance layout.

The parasitics can be useful too: power and ground planes are often placed next to each other to improve power noise bypassing through inter-plane capacitance. Controlled impedance *transmission lines* can be fashioned right on the board using carefully-specified traces and reference plane distances.